# Make links in textview open WebView in Android app

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, clickable, htmltext

Hi I want to make links from TextView of my app open the `WebView Activity` also inside my app.

I am able to handle link clicks using a custom class extending `LinkMovementMethod` class. Below is the code:

```
public class CustomLinkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
    private static Context                  movementContext;
    private static CustomLinkMovementMethod linkMovementMethod  = new CustomLinkMovementMethod();
    public boolean onTouchEvent(android.widget.TextView widget, android.text.Spannable buffer, android.view.MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            URLSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, URLSpan.class);
            if (link.length != 0)
            {
                String url = link[0].getURL();
                if (url.contains("https"))
                {
                    Log.d("Link", url);
                    Toast.makeText(movementContext, "https Link was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (url.contains("tel"))
                {
                    Log.d("Link", url);
                    Toast.makeText(movementContext, "Tel was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (url.contains("mailto"))
                {
                    Log.d("Link", url);
                    Toast.makeText(movementContext, "Mail link was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (url.contains("http"))
                {
                    Log.d("Link", url);
                    Toast.makeText(movementContext, "http Link was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (url.contains("www"))
                {
                    Log.d("Link", url);
                    Toast.makeText(movementContext, "www Link was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }
    public static android.text.method.MovementMethod getInstance(Context c){
        movementContext = c;
        return linkMovementMethod;
    }
}
```

here is the layout for my MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setMovementMethod(CustomLinkMovementMethod.getInstance(MainActivity.this));
        //textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


        String customHtml2 ="<div>not valid => <a href='http://facebook.com'>http://facebook</a></div>" +
                "           <div><a href='http://www.facebook.com'>http://www.facebook.com</a></div>" +
                "           <div>http://www.google.com  <= a regular link<div>" +
                "           <div>www.google.com  <= a regular link<div>" +
                "           <div><a href='http://google.com'>http://google.com</a></div>" +
                "           <div><strong style='font-family:Arial, Verdana;font-weight:normal;'>http://www.google.com</strong></div>" +
                "           <div><strong style='font-family:Arial, Verdana;font-weight:normal;'></strong></div>" +
                "";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(customHtml2));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the attributes below for the textview makes the onTouchEvent method in CustomLinkMovement class not to be fired and open the default web browser. If I remove them links like this http://www.google.com is not clickable since it is not enclosed in 
tag.

```
android:linksClickable="true"
 android:autoLink="all"
```

The problem is I want them to be clickable even if the link is not enclosed in  tags and be able to use `android:linksClickable="true" and android:autoLink="all"` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

the only constraints is that your address should start with `http://`

Comment: The code you provided works, but html links inside <a></a> tags like <div><a href='http://www.myURL.com'>myURL</a></div> do not work. but when I remove Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL); and android:linksClickable="true" and android:autoLink="all" codes the <a> tags are clickable but all other links that are not surrounded with <a> tags dont work.

Comment: I found this and this solved my problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/android-developers/uHxRJ8EEBcM/pPChJMnQZgIJ